# Mesh Material color stumper when using with a single pixel's getImageData in Three.js

Tags: colors, three.js, html5-canvas, getimagedata

This question is strictly about one color materials (the same amount of data that one single pixel would have) and not textures.

When using `getImageData`, I can get the color/opacity of a specified pixel in a 2d image in a canvas just fine; resulting with something like: 50,41,26,255 (for example).

But my question is: instead of having to use a rgba-to-hex system like `toString(16)` (then using string manipulation and also the opacity/alpha value separately since that is 0-1 and not 00-FF), etc, for converting, when specifying the exact pixel-color-and-opacity data for `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial` colors...

Is there a more efficient way?

Ideally, instead of:

```
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
    {color:0x33AA55, transparent:true, opacity:0.8, side: THREE.DoubleSide})
```

And then all the heaps of conversion code required for making that

To have something like:

```
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
    {rgba-color:(ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data), side: THREE.DoubleSide});
```

Comment: this is not really a question but a suggestion for a feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As things are right now you do need to convert it. I don't see a convenience method happening for this, as it is a very specific use-case. It isn't all that bad doing the conversion manually anyway: if you also want to handle the opacity you'll have to tackle that value specifically anyway since `THREE.Color` doesn't use it.

```
var data = context.getImageData( x, y, 1, 1 ).data;
var floats = data.slice( 0, 4 ).map( function( val ) { return val / 255; });
var color = THREE.Color( float[0], float[1], float[2] );
var opacity = float[4];
```

Not exactly heaps of code, but if it bothers you too much then create a function for it.

Don't use string manipulation, that's error-prone and inefficient.